# Enhanced Redmine issues interface

Tags: redmine

We are using Redmine a lot for the issues management but we also use pivotaltracker for our features requests.

The problem with our Redmine issues is that it's just too long to update (compare with pivotaltracker).

Does anyone have somekind of plugin/skin to allow the users to update the issues from the issues list without actually opening it ?

Comment: What do you mean when you said _"update the issues from the issues list without actually opening it?"_

Comment: To change the status of an issue, you need to click on it, then click "update" and then got back to your issue list.
In pivotal you got a big button on every item of your list. Clicking this button sets it to next step in the process (start-finished-delivered....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you missed this feature in Redmine. From the issues list, right click on the issue to update its status without opening:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it did it. We never realized this because there is a little lag (1.5sec) while right clicking